# Trouble when operating with list items referenced by variable indices

Tags: python

I recently got started with python, and I wanted to make an algebraic tool to help me with synthetic polynomial division.

To that end, I wrote a script that would store the dividends and products in a list, and use variables, namely the divisor and number of the column being operated on, in order to perform the calculation.

This would provide flexibility of size for the degree of the dividend polynomial. The code is pasted below, with `p_list` and `d_list` being the product and dividend list, respectively. The product list is initially filled with placeholders. The `opno` variable stores the number of the column being operated on.

```
p_list = []
for i in d_list:
    p_list.append('o')
p_list[0] = d_list[0]
p_list[1] = int(divisor)*int(p_list[0])+int(d_list[1])
opno = 2
for x in range(0, len(p_list)):
    opno2 = int(opno)- 1
    p_list[int(opno)] = int(divisor)*int(p_list[int(int(opno)-1)])+int(d_list[int(opno)])
    opno = int(opno) + 1
```

However, when I run this, Python returns the
`IndexError: list index out of range` message, stating that the index error is in this line:

```
p_list[int(opno)] = int(divisor)*int(p_list[int(opno2)])+int(d_list[int(opno)])
```

Edit: I did run tests by printing the lists before the problematic line, and the lists are sequences of numbers.

Comment: So, what is your question? Have you tried printing the numbers you are passing as indices to try to see what's going on?

Comment: What type of objects are in `d_list`?  Ints?  Floats?  Something else?

Comment: Could you maybe explain exactly what this script is supposed to do?  Lots of pieces of the code look like they were added randomly instead of with any specific intent, so it's hard to infer what any of it is supposed to be doing -- variables are declared that are never used for anything, values are converted redundantly to the same type multiple times in the same expression, and you have a loop that iterates over list indices without using the actual index, instead overwriting the same spot in the list over and over again (which may not necessarily even be within bounds).

Comment: How is `d_list` defined? Does it have at least 2 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in question has at least one clear reason why an IndexError will occur.  Here's all the code you need to see:

```
opno = 2
for x in range(0, len(p_list)):
    opno2 = opno - 1
    p_list[opno] = int(divisor)*int(p_list[int(opno-1)])+int(d_list[opno])
    opno = opno + 1
```

Here, you're going to start with `opno` being 2, and then you're going to loop once for each item in `p_list`.  Each time through the loop, you set `p_list[opno]` to something, and then increment the value of `opno`.  This would work if you were starting `opno` at 0.  But since you're starting it at 2, you're going to run off the end of `p_list` and try to set two places in that list that don't exist.  You'll never get a chance to try the second place, because the first one will throw an `IndexError` like the one you're seeing.